# Java Jlist text center align

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlist

I have a `JList` on a panel.

How can I **center align** the text in the `JList`?
I can't seem to find the settings anywhere for the model?

I have looked for align settings on the GUI but cant seem to find any there.

Answer (score 13):

This has nothing to do with the model since it involves the view, the ListCellRenderer to be specific. One solution; get the renderer and set its horizontalAlignment to SwingConstants.CENTER. Assuming that you're not using a custom cell renderer you could for example do:

```
DefaultListCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultListCellRenderer) myJList.getCellRenderer();
renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
JList list = new JList(args);
DefaultListCellRenderer renderer =  (DefaultListCellRenderer)list.getCellRenderer();  
renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers seem outdated or at least they did not work for me, I solved like this:

```
 list.setCellRenderer((list, project, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus) -> {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(value.getName())
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            return label;
        });
```